# Popup when data is looped from php CI

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter, popup

I have a tag of html for a href. This is my code:

```
<a href='#' class='popup' onclick='getPopup();'>$item->NAMA_NASABAH</a>
```

the code is sended from ci controller using ajax, and looped from database. So i have many a href. When i try to click the `a href`, the popup will show up.

here code in javascript:

```
function getPopup(){
    alert('popup');
    dialog.dialog("open");
}
dialog = $( "#loginform" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 600,
      width: 400,
      modal: true
});

<div id="loginform" title="Create new user">TEST</div>
```

when i try to run my application, the alert is running, but my popup not showup. How can i fix it?, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPopup(){
    dialog = $( "#loginform" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 600,
      width: 400,
      modal: true
    dialog.dialog("open");
}
```

The dialog must in above of open syntax.